# Unity Best HTTP/2 Reguest With Form

Tags: c#, multithreading, http, unity-game-engine, https

I have a problem with the current version of Best HTTP/2 I hope to solve, when I send a request (POST) and attach a Form with it and choose the form type to Multipart, an error message appears saying: RST Stream frame Error: PROTOCOL_ERROR(1)
I don't know if the reason is the site's support for HTTP/3 requests. But it is supposed to deal with the lower requests in the version automatically. And also with the use of UnityRequest with HTTP/1.1 It works for me, I don't know what's really wrong.

This is the full message:

```
{"tid":83,"div":"HTTP2Stream","msg":"[3] RST Stream frame ([HTTP2RST_StreamFrame Header: [HTTP2FrameHeaderAndPayload Length: 4, Type: RST_STREAM, Flags: 00000000, StreamId: 3, PayloadOffset: 0, DontUseMemPool: False], Error: PROTOCOL_ERROR(1)]) received in state HalfClosedLocal!","stack":"  at Connections.HTTP2.HTTP2Stream.ProcessIncomingFrames (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] outgoingFrames)  in A:\\..\\..\\..\\UnityProject\\backend\\Assets\\Best HTTP\\Source\\Connections\\HTTP2\\HTTP2Stream.cs:392 \r  at Connections.HTTP2.HTTP2Stream.AddFrame (Connections.HTTP2.HTTP2FrameHeaderAndPayload frame, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] outgoingFrames)  in A:\\..\\..\\..\\UnityProject\\backend\\Assets\\Best HTTP\\Source\\Connections\\HTTP2\\HTTP2Stream.cs:194 \r  at Connections.HTTP2.HTTP2Handler.RunHandler ()  in A:\\..\\..\\..\\UnityProject\\backend\\Assets\\Best HTTP\\Source\\Connections\\HTTP2\\HTTP2Handler.cs:185 \r  at Connections.HTTPConnection.ThreadFunc ()  in A:\\..\\..\\..\\UnityProject\\backend\\Assets\\Best HTTP\\Source\\Connections\\HTTPConnection.cs:122 \r  at PlatformSupport.Threading.ThreadedRunner+<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<RunLongLiving>b__0 (System.Object param) [0x00000] in A:\\..\\..\\..\\UnityProject\\backend\\Assets\\Best HTTP\\Source\\PlatformSupport\\Threading\\ThreadedRunner.cs:98 \r  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 \r  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00000] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 \r  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00000] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 \r  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state) [0x00000] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 \r  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart (System.Object obj) [0x00000] in <eae584ce26bc40229c1b1aa476bfa589>:0 ","ctxs":[{"TypeName": "HTTP2Stream", "Hash": -1208815744, "id": 3},{"TypeName": "HTTPRequest", "Hash": 350817792},{"TypeName": "HTTP2Handler", "Hash": 964403712, "Connection": 738886912}],"t":637835483138909554,"ll":"Error","bh":1}
```

Comment: A multipart message contains Mime Attachments.  Each Mime attachment starts with a new line with two dashes at the beginning of the line.  See following for an example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for this, I have discovered the cause of the error now, I was trying to execute the request with the same HTTPRequest object and it was working in normal requests (GET, POST) without Forms-data, by updating the request information, because I wanted to keep the connection with Host information and make the connection Seamless, seems to have a problem updating headers when updating forms and submitting the request the error occurs, I tried creating a new HTTPRequest object and getting rid of the old one in every request update and it seems to work fine, I figured it would reconnect from the beginning and take about 1000 ms to respond but Beautiful communication seems to be continuous